# Use Adobe Reader to open a PDF from own app using WebViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, pdf, uiwebview

In my iPad app, I have a button that opens a document using a WebViewController to view the file.

For certain PDF documents that were viewable in iOS4, opening them on iOS5 now crashes the app.  The same thing happens in Mail if I try to view these PDF documents that are attached to emails.  However, if I tap and hold in Mail and select "Open with Adobe Reader," the document opens successfully.

Is there a way to change what is used to generate the view of the PDF in the WebViewController to use the Adobe Reader viewer, rather than the native PDF viewer?

I would like to do this directly within the same WebViewController, rather than using a UIDocumentInteractionController popover that shows the "Open in Adobe Reader" prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge the only way to do this would be if the Adobe Reader had a custom URL Scheme.  You could 'intercept' the URL with a PDF extension and re-craft the URL to use the URL Scheme.  However, to my knowledge Adobe Reader doesn't provide this URL scheme.

That being said, you can give the user the option to open files with a viewer of their choice (if they save it locally).  If Adobe Reader is registered to open PDF files (and I'm sure it is) then you can create an 'Open With' button to determine how it should be opened.  It will show all programs that can open a PDF file.  For more information on this, check the Apple documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1