# pdf reader for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm new in iPhone, I want to create application to open pdf document like Adobe Reader
and contain many features like:

- sets and gets bookmarks
- allows user to add comments in any paragraph
- allows user to add highlight
- allows for the search for a word (supporting Arabic and English)
- allows for leaves movement (optional)

is there is any code to do this?

Note: I tried fastpdfkit but it is not allows to add comments and highlight and not support arabic search

Comment: No .. you should implement your own one.

Comment: is there is anyway to link adobe reader app of iphone to my application??

Comment: check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988563/use-adobe-reader-to-open-a-pdf-from-own-app-using-webviewcontroller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988563/use-adobe-reader-to-open-a-pdf-from-own-app-using-webviewcontroller)

Answer (score -1):

If you are up for it, I have a high- and low-level PDF Library. It's C++, which is not what you are asking for, but I already know that a couple of my users are looking for an IOS adaptation, and one is working on it.

If you are up for the task (of adapting), it might be useful to you. Anyways, if interested, check it out at [www.pdfhummus.com](http://www.pdfhummus.com).