# iOS Open Document with External App from UIWebVIew

Tags: ios, uiwebview, external, document

I have a `UIWebView`. When a link which contains a document is clicked, I want to open that document in a external app (office, openoffice, etc) but not inside the `UIWebView`.

I know how to do it for emails:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"mailto"]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
    return NO;
}
return YES;
```

}

Is there any way to do this but for documents?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**
That's what I have done:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL* possibleDocumentURL = [request mainDocumentURL];
    NSString* extension = [[possibleDocumentURL lastPathComponent] pathExtension];

    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqual:@"mailto"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;

    }else if ([extension isEqualToString:@"pdf"] || [extension isEqualToString:@"docx"]){

        NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:possibleDocumentURL];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse
*resp, NSData *respData, NSError *error){ stringByAppendingString:names[names.count-1]];
        NSString *fileName = @"myFile";
        NSString * path = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        NSError *errorC = nil;
        BOOL success = [respData writeToFile:path
                                         options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete
                                           error:&errorC];

        if (success) {
            self.documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
             self.documentController.delegate = self;
             [self.documentController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
         } else {
             NSLog(@"fail: %@", errorC.description);
         }
    }];

        return NO;
   }

   return YES; 
}
```

The problem now is that the `UIDocumentInteractionController` only shows `Mail` and `Messages` apps. I need the apps for opening `pdf`, `docx`, etc files.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `[UIWebViewDelegate webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType: navigationType:]` you can check if the URL looks like it points to a document. The simplest way to do that is just to look for pdf, doc etc. If you want it to be nicer, then use UTTypes.

```
NSURL* possibleDocumentURL = [request mainDocumentURL];
NSString* extension = [[possibleDocumentURL lastPathComponent] pathExtension];
// TODO: check ending
```

If it's a URL to a document, then just  download the document. You can now either open a `DocumentPreviewController`, `UIDocumentInteractionController` or `QLPreviewController`. The user will still need to select where the file should go.

If the app you want to open it in supports a custom URL scheme you could pass the URL or the file itself directly to it without user interaction.

Comment: thanks for your response :) is it possible to open directly an external app? for example, if I get a .docx file I would like to open office, if I get a pdf file I would like to open adobe reader, and so on... I have tried the   DocumentPreviewController but I don't get it to work

Comment: You can open external apps directly only if they support a custom url scheme. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988563/use-adobe-reader-to-open-a-pdf-from-own-app-using-webviewcontroller Adobe Reader doesn't have a custom url. Good Reader has http://www.goodiware.com/gr-man-manage.html#link

Answer (score 4):

UIDocumentInteractionController will work for you.

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html)

[Great step by step tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-previewing-and-opening-documents--mobile-15130)